# Python twisted TLS, get raw packets data

Tags: python, ssl, twisted.web

Is it possible using a Python twisted web server to access the raw bytes of TLS Handshake packets for further processing, such as counting `ja3` for client-hello?

I tried use call `dataReceived` method but its impossible by web server.

I think need redefine custom class for `TLSMemoryBIOProtocol`, but I can't call constructor for it.

```py
class CustomTLSMemoryBIOProtocol(tls.TLSMemoryBIOProtocol):
    def __init__(self, factory, wrappedProtocol, _connectWrapped=True, client_hello = b""):
        super().__init__(factory, wrappedProtocol, _connectWrapped=True)
        self.client_hello = client_hello

    
    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if len(bytes) > 5 and bytes[:3] == b'\x16\x03\x01' and bytes[5] == 1:
            print("CustomTLSMemoryBIOProtocol dataReceived")
            self.client_hello = bytes
        super().dataReceived(bytes)
```

It's my current code:

```py
def get_https_endpoint():
    ssl_context = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(
        "services/web/certs/key.pem", "services/web/certs/cert.pem"
    )
    https_factory = server.Site(IndexResource())

    return reactor.listenSSL(
        config["service"]["port"]["https"], https_factory, ssl_context
    )
```

Comment: what does *counting ja3 for client-hello* mean?

Comment: Needed get access for client hello packet, calculate ja3 hash and write it at via logging. The crux of the question is getting tls handshake raw packet data at twisted web server, ja3 its example.